# Why next_post_link have to call twice in order to function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating the pre/next posts navigator using the following code in wordpress 4.8 and php 7:

```
<span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', true); ?></span>
<span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true); ?></span>
```

The previous link works well, but the next link never displayed.

Then I tried the following code:

```
<span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', true); ?></span>
<?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true); ?>
<span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true); ?></span>
```

It calls next_post_link twice, and now it works as expected. However, this solution is simple and ugly. I beleive there is something wrong with my code or wordpress settings.

Here is the whole malfunction code snippet:

```
<?php if ( array_intersect($excluded_terms, $categories_id_list) ) { ?>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', true); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', true); ?></span> 
<?php } else { ?>
    <span class="nav-previous"><?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', '%title', false, $excluded_terms); ?></span>
    <span class="nav-next"><?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', '%title', false, $excluded_terms); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Only previous_post_link shows correctly.

Here is a list of installed and enable plugins on my site:

- Akismet Anti-Spam
- Book Review Library
- Cat Generator Avatars
- Child Theme Configurator
- Comments - wpDiscuz
- Custom Post Type UI
- Google XML Sitemaps
- Jetpack
- List category posts
- Mailgun
- OnePress Image Elevator
- Simple Lightbox
- Table of Contents Plus
- UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
- WP Config File Editor
- WP Super Cache
- WP-Optimize

Any suggestion would appreicate.

Comment: Is it possible that you're on the first post while testing this, so there IS NO next post? That would cause the function to appear to not work the first time.

Comment: @GregBurkett Thanks for the quick reply. I have checked all posts have the same issue, only prev shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled the Book Review Library plugin, then it fixes.